# Get random child record without accessing individual parent record - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a quiz like website.

I have categories, questions and choices as tables.

What i want is, where i list my categories, when i click on category, i want it to take me to the *categories/1/questions/<**random question**> path*.

*the relationships are set up*

here is what i have so far.

**index.erb.html (of categories)**

```
    <ul class="categories-list">
      <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <% if category.header %>
        <% @count = @count + 1 %>
          <li class="panel header" id="cat<%= @count %>">
            <a href="#"><%= category.title %></a>
            <small>781 of 781 questions remaining</small>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li class="panel sub hidden subcat<%= @count %>" >
            <%= link_to category.title, category_question_path(category,category.questions.limit(1).order("RAND()")) %>
            <small>781 of 781 questions remaining</small>
          </li>
        <% end %>

      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

**categories-controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @count = 0
    @categories = Category.order(:tag)

  end
```

Comment: What is the problem with `category,category.questions.limit(1).order("RAND()")` query ? What is your DBMS

Comment: its local environment so sqlite3. i get this as a url. `http://localhost:3000/categories/2/questions/%23%3CQuestion::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fcd441d7860%3E`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most generic way to do this (independent of database vendor):

```
category.questions.offset(rand(category.questions.count)).first
```

Vendor specific queries are also possible:

```
category.questions.order("RANDOM()").first # postgres
category.questions.order("RAND()").first # mysql
```

Define new action `/random_question`:

```
def random_question
  category = Category.find params[:category_id]
  question = category.questions.offset(rand(category.questions.count)).first
  redirect_to question_path(question)
end
```

Comment: the random record i want it to be on the question path no the category sir.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou you need random question from given category, right?

Comment: yes all categories are listed, when i click on a category i go straight to a random question other that clicked category.

Comment: where do i input this `category.questions.offset(rand(category.questions.count)).first`

Comment: if its here `<%= link_to category.title, category_question_path(category,category.questions.offset(rand(category.questions.count)).first) %>` it gives me error.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou I think it's better to find random question when link is clicked. Create a `random_question` action and link to it. No need to find random question before it's actually needed.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou after finding random question in `random_question` method, redirect user to normal "show" method with this question.

Comment: ok so how do i implement it fully in the view? i am bit new to rails, do i also have to create route and link to that route instead? and from there redirect to show action of questions controller? is that it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89574/discussion-between-dimakura-and-petros-kyriakou).